# Frequent audio issues on ASUS X555LF (Dummy output, missing mic, etc)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, asus, microphone

Throughout multiple Ubuntu versions for the time I had this laptop I had audio issues. Everything works on a fresh install, so last time after fiddling with all kinds of alsa/pulse related things and seemingly getting things fubar I had to reinstall Ubuntu. Fortunately I had the idea of saving a log generated by the [Alsa Information Script](https://www.alsa-project.org/wiki/AlsaInfo) right after a fresh install, So I'm hoping this might help.

Currently I'm connected to an external monitor through hdmi, and sound is working there, but nothing else is. Both my internal output and input devices are nowhere to be found.

[Here's the original log from 2020-03-16](https://pastebin.com/GgvDUE0u)

[Here's the one I just got](https://pastebin.com/gSEqHCCZ)

Running them on a diff tool, it immediately stands out that this block changed:

```
!!Soundcards recognised by ALSA
!!-----------------------------
 0 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel HDMI
                      HDA Intel HDMI at 0x9b31c000 irq 52
 1 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0x9b318000 irq 51
```

Card #1 (PCH) is now missing.

These dmesg logs seem pretty wild too:

```
[    8.815205] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20190703/nsarguments-59)
[    8.918031] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: azx_get_response timeout, switching to polling mode: last cmd=0x000f0000
[    9.922087] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: No response from codec, disabling MSI: last cmd=0x000f0000
[   10.934092] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: Codec #0 probe error; disabling it...
[   11.942089] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x000f0000
[   12.954031] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: azx_get_response timeout, switching to single_cmd mode: last cmd=0x000f0000
[   12.954279] hdaudio hdaudioC1D0: no AFG or MFG node found
[   12.954283] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: no codecs initialized
[   14.025932] EXT4-fs (sda8): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```